# Datapump export and import 5Gb table

Tags: oracle, datapump

In oracle 10g, In Data Pump I am Exporting and Importing a 5GB table from source to destination. In the 5Gb table the data is added and some rows are updated. This time I need to only export and import changed data and updated data, but not the entire 5GB of data.

Comment: tried creating a smaller tale with where clause shwoing only the rows you need and then export it .

Answer (score 0):

Data Pump can append data to an existing table, or "overwrite" it (truncate, replace). It can not insert **AND update** (merge) data.